# NoSuchFileException When reading input file

Tags: java

I have an input file data, name `input.dat` which is stored in the `src/main/resources`. When I tried to read from this input file as follows:

```
String[] lines = Files.readAllLines(new File("input.dat").toPath()).toArray(new String[0]);
```

I received the following exception:

`java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: input.dat`

Can anyone help me with what did I do wrong here? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The java file you are running is probably not in the same directory as the file `input.dat`.

When referencing the file in your Java code include the *relative path* to it. If the java file that you are running is in `src/main` then the relative path would be `resources/input.dat`.

In that case, your code would look like this:

`String[] lines = Files.readAllLines(new File("resources/input.dat").toPath()).toArray(new String[0]);`

Hope this helped you and if you have any further questions please feel free to post a comment below!

Comment: Hi Michael, thank for your help, I had to replace the whole part as new File("src/main/resources/input.dat") then it worked. But I have a question, when I run as Java Application then it works fine, but if I build the jar file with maven, then run this jar file, then it has again the NoSuchFileException. Do you have idea why it happened?

Comment: Yes, that is a very common problem. It can be caused by many issues. Perhaps the file is not properly included in the build system or in the classpath.

Comment: That's not the best solution. Obviously, he's using Maven, thus, the way to go is to use the classloader: `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("input.dat")`

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not too familiar with Maven. If you feel that it is necessary to include that solution then post your own answer.

Comment: @AKSW hi AKSW, can you please explain me how this solution work? Thank you

Comment: @Soe Some developers believe that the Maven directory structure will be replicated in the .jar after compilation. Therefore, they are tempted to try to open the data resource with a strategy similar to yours. In other words, they believe they have to handle the Maven directory structure themselves, including the absolute path to the current .jar location. This does not work. First, one must keep in mind that Maven does not "push" its directory structure in .jars.

Comment: @Soe Those folder `src/main/java`, `src/main/resources`, etc. are just convention, please simply look at the jar file generated once you called `mvn package`

Answer (score 0):

Replace input.dat with the exact path of input.dat. Such as `C:/Users/Soe/Desktop/input.dat`